# Python error: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, console

i need to write a small json data object with python, but when i use this, it don't work, what do i wrong?

This is for the newest version of Python

```py
import urllib, json
import requests
import json

with open('locaties.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for parkeerlocaties in data['parkeerlocaties']:
        for locatie in parkeerlocaties['parkeerlocatie']:
            for title in locatie['title']:
                print("Hello World")
```

```
{"parkeerlocaties":[{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"Fietsenstalling Tolhuisplein","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.9032801,52.3824545]}","type":"Fietspunt","url":"https:\/\/www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeren-verkeer\/fiets\/fietsparkeren\/gemeentelijke\/","urltitle":"www.amsterdam.nl\/fiets","adres":"Buiksloterweg 3","postcode":"1031 CC","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":"Alleen toegankelijk voor abonnementhouders van Tolhuisplein, automatische stalling"}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"Fietsenstalling Paradiso","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.8833735,52.3621851]}","type":"Fietspunt","url":"https:\/\/www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeren-verkeer\/fiets\/fietsparkeren\/gemeentelijke\/","urltitle":"www.amsterdam.nl\/fiets","adres":"Weteringschans 4 A","postcode":"1017 SG","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":"Maximale parkeerduur 28 dagen, stalling met toezicht"}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"Fietsenstalling Zuidplein","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.8719467,52.3398642]}","type":"Fietspunt","url":"https:\/\/www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeren-verkeer\/fiets\/fietsparkeren\/gemeentelijke\/","urltitle":"www.amsterdam.nl\/fiets","adres":"Zuidplein 5","postcode":"1077 XV","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":"Maximale parkeerduur 28 dagen, stalling met toezicht"}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"Fietsenstalling Station Rai (gesloten tot februari 2019)","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.8905079,52.339392]}","type":"Fietspunt","url":"https:\/\/www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeren-verkeer\/fiets\/fietsparkeren\/gemeentelijke\/","urltitle":"www.amsterdam.nl\/fiets","adres":"Europaboulevard 4","postcode":"1083 AD","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":"Sluit voor renovatie op 21 juli 2018. Er zijn rond het station extra parkeerplekken voor fiets gemaakt."}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"P+R Zeeburg","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.9607015,52.3719632]}","type":"P+R","url":"https:\/\/www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeren-verkeer\/parkeren-reizen\/#h4f9f93f8-875b-4d18-936a-c1eba9d6f198","urltitle":"www.amsterdam.nl\/penr ","adres":"Zuiderzeeweg 46 a","postcode":"1095KJ","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":"","OV_bus":"bus 37 Noord - Amstelstation vv","OV_tram":"tram 26 Ijburg - Centraal Station vv","OV":"tram;GVB_26_1;08240, bus;GVB_37_2;08134"}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"Weekend P+R VUmc","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.8611063,52.3361167]}","type":"P+R","url":"https:\/\/www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeren-verkeer\/parkeren-reizen\/#hdce18cfd-fc8f-4728-be57-2d9a23b494d9","urltitle":"www.amsterdam.nl\/penr","adres":"Gustav Mahlerlaan 3004","postcode":"1081 LA","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":"","OV_metro":"metro 51 Isolatorweg - Centraal Station vv (maart 2019 t\/m eind 2020), metro 50 met overstap Overamstel op 51 Centraal Station","OV_tram":"tram 24 VU medisch centrum - Centraal Station vv, tram 5 Amstelveen - Van Hallstraat vv","OV":"metro;GVB_50_1;07343;09563, tram;GVB_24_1;07350, tram;GVB_5_1;07410"}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"P+R Bos en Lommer","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.8453671,52.379131]}","type":"P+R","url":"https:\/\/www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeren-verkeer\/parkeren-reizen\/#h9434503d-d323-4331-b792-5210ce062c42","urltitle":"www.amsterdam.nl\/penr ","adres":"Leeuwendalersweg 23 b","postcode":"1055JE","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":"","OV_bus":"bus 21 Geuzenveld - Centraal Station vv","OV_tram":"tram 7 Slotermeer - Azartplein vv","OV":"bus;GVB_21_1;03060, tram;GVB_7_1;03167"}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"P+R Sloterdijk","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.8384209,52.3900128]}","type":"P+R","url":"https:\/\/www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeren-verkeer\/parkeren-reizen\/#h628fb483-dec3-4a9d-9d52-50136e9639ec","urltitle":"www.amsterdam.nl\/penr","adres":"Piarcoplein 1","postcode":"1043DW","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":"","OV_bus":"bus 22 Station Sloterdijk - Muiderpoortstation vv","OV_metro":"metro 50 Isolatorweg - Gein vv, overstap 51 op Station Zuid \/ Station RAI \/ Overamstel","OV_tram":"tram 19 Station Sloterdijk - Diemen vv","OV_trein":"Treinen tussen station Sloterdijk en de stations CS, Muiderpoort en Amstel (GVB P+R-kaart niet geldig)","OV":"tram;GVB_19_1;02361;00014, metro;GVB_50_1;02295;09563, metro;GVB_51_1;*09563, bus;GVB_22_1;02367;00001"}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"P+R Olympisch Stadion","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.8539215,52.3440266]}","type":"P+R","url":"https:\/\/www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeren-verkeer\/parkeren-reizen\/#h4567b083-9fea-4848-882a-280b6abc7853","urltitle":"www.amsterdam.nl\/penr ","adres":"Olympisch Stadion 44","postcode":"1076DE","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":"","OV_tram":"tram 24 VU medisch centrum - Centraal Station vv","OV":"tram;GVB_24_1;07121"}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"P+R Johan Cruijff ArenA","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.9405734,52.3137551]}","type":"P+R","url":"https:\/\/www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeren-verkeer\/parkeren-reizen\/#h1dfa5189-98e8-42ce-8119-ce74f2451969","urltitle":"www.amsterdam.nl\/penr","adres":"Burgemeester Stramanweg 130","postcode":"1101EP","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":"","OV_metro":"metro 54 Gein - Centraal Station vv","OV_trein":"Treinen tussen station Bijlmer Arena en stations Amstel, Muiderpoort en Centraal Station (GVB P+R-kaart niet geldig)","OV":"metro;GVB_54_1;09522"}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"Amsterdamse Poort (P21 t\/m 24)","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.9626214,52.3192019]}","type":"CommercieleParkeergarage","url":"https:\/\/www.q-park.nl\/nl-nl\/parkeren\/amsterdam\/amsterdamse-poort-p21\/","urltitle":"Amsterdamse Poort P21","adres":"Bijlmerdreef 700","postcode":"1103DS","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":""}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"P18 HES\/ ROC","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.9466199,52.3152543]}","type":"Parkeergarage","url":"https:\/\/www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeren-verkeer\/parkeergarages\/parkeergarages\/garage-p18-hes-roc\/","urltitle":"Bekijk P18 HES\/ ROC op www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeergarages","adres":"Fraijlemaborg 131","postcode":"1102CV","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":""}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"P1 ArenA","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.9405851,52.3137433]}","type":"Parkeergarage","url":"https:\/\/www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeren-verkeer\/parkeergarages\/parkeergarages\/parkeergarage-p1\/","urltitle":"Bekijk P1 ArenA op www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeergarages","adres":"Burgemeester Stramanweg 130","postcode":"1101EP","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":""}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"P10 Plaza ArenA","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.9409531,52.3080762]}","type":"Parkeergarage","url":"https:\/\/www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeren-verkeer\/parkeergarages\/parkeergarages\/p10-plaza-arena\/","urltitle":"Bekijk P10 Plaza ArenA op www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeergarages","adres":"Herikerbergweg 288","postcode":"1101CT","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":""}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"P 3 Mikado","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.9413266,52.3103066]}","type":"Parkeergarage","url":"https:\/\/www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeren-verkeer\/parkeergarages\/parkeergarages\/garage-p3-mikado\/","urltitle":"Bekijk P3 Mikado op www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeergarages","adres":"De entree 228","postcode":"1101EE","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":""}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"RAI Parking","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.8921615,52.3383996]}","type":"CommercieleParkeergarage","url":"https:\/\/www.rai.nl\/nl\/contact-bereikbaarheid-en-parkeren\/parkeren-bij-rai-amsterdam\/","urltitle":"Rai Parking","adres":"Europaboulevard 24","postcode":"1078GZ","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":""}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"Qpark Eurocenter","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.8888094,52.3358123]}","type":"CommercieleParkeergarage","url":"https:\/\/www.q-park.nl\/nl-nl\/parkeren\/amsterdam\/eurocenter\/","urltitle":"Qpark Eurocenter ","adres":"Barbara Strozzilaan 342","postcode":"1083HN","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":""}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"Qpark Mahler","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.8723915,52.3377672]}","type":"CommercieleParkeergarage","url":"https:\/\/www.q-park.nl\/nl-nl\/parkeren\/amsterdam\/mahler\/","urltitle":"Qpark Mahler","adres":"Claude Debussylaan 42","postcode":"1082MD","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":""}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"Olympisch Stadion","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.8539215,52.3440266]}","type":"CommercieleParkeergarage","url":"http:\/\/www.p1.nl\/parkeren\/parkeergarage-olympisch-stadion\/","urltitle":"P1 Parkeergarage Olympisch Stadion ","adres":"Olympisch Stadion 44","postcode":"1076DE","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":""}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"Interparking Oranjekwartier Amsterdam","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.839149,52.3546448]}","type":"CommercieleParkeergarage","url":"http:\/\/www.interparking.nl\/nl-NL\/find-parking\/Oranjekwartier\/","urltitle":"Interparking Oranjekwartier Amsterdam","adres":"Carnapstraat 200","postcode":"1062KZ","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":""}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"Bomengarage P2 (Boven 't IJ) ","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.9388323,52.3994577]}","type":"Parkeergarage","url":"https:\/\/www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeren-verkeer\/parkeergarages\/parkeergarages\/garage-p2bomengarage\/","urltitle":"Bekijk Bomengarage P2 op www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeergarages","adres":"Buikslotermeerplein 237","postcode":"1025 XB","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":""}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"Qpark Westergasfabriek","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.8662388,52.3847072]}","type":"CommercieleParkeergarage","url":"https:\/\/www.q-park.nl\/nl-nl\/parkeren\/amsterdam\/westergasfabriek\/","urltitle":"Qpark Amsterdam Westergasfabriek","adres":"Van Bleiswijkstraat 8","postcode":"1051DG","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":""}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"Qpark Europarking","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.8766781,52.3699218]}","type":"CommercieleParkeergarage","url":"https:\/\/www.q-park.nl\/nl-nl\/parkeren\/amsterdam\/europarking\/","urltitle":"Qpark Europarking","adres":"Marnixstraat 250","postcode":"1016TL","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":""}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"Qpark Byzantium","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.8793897,52.3618422]}","type":"CommercieleParkeergarage","url":"https:\/\/www.q-park.nl\/nl-nl\/parkeren\/amsterdam\/byzantium\/","urltitle":"Qpark Amsterdam Byzantium","adres":"Tesselschadestraat 1","postcode":"1054ET","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":""}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"Piet Heingarage","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.9173751,52.3773883]}","type":"Parkeergarage","url":"https:\/\/www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeren-verkeer\/parkeergarages\/parkeergarages\/parkeergarage-piet\/","urltitle":"Bekijk Piet Heingarage op www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeergarages","adres":"Piet Heinkade 59","postcode":"1019GM","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":""}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"Parking Centrum Oosterdok","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.9092051,52.3761913]}","type":"CommercieleParkeergarage","url":"http:\/\/www.parkingcentrumoosterdok.nl\/","urltitle":"Parking Centrum Oosterdok","adres":"Oosterdoksstraat 150","postcode":"1011AD","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":""}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"Markenhoven","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.908618,52.3696328]}","type":"Parkeergarage","url":"https:\/\/www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeren-verkeer\/parkeergarages\/parkeergarages\/garage-markenhoven\/","urltitle":"Bekijk Markenhoven op www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeergarages","adres":"Anne Frankstraat 220","postcode":"1011 MP","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":""}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"(P1) Parking Waterlooplein","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.9043352,52.3689665]}","type":"CommercieleParkeergarage","url":"http:\/\/www.parkereninwaterlooplein.nl\/","urltitle":"Parkeergarage Waterlooplein ","adres":"Valkenburgerstraat 238","postcode":"1011ND","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":""}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"Stadhuis - Muziektheater","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.9018035,52.3670615]}","type":"Parkeergarage","url":"https:\/\/www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeren-verkeer\/parkeergarages\/parkeergarages\/garage-stadhuis\/","urltitle":" Bekijk Stadhuis-Muziektheater op www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeergarages","adres":"Waterlooplein 28","postcode":"1011PG","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":""}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"Parkeergarage Prins & Keizer","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.891798,52.3622906]}","type":"CommercieleParkeergarage","url":"http:\/\/www.apcoa.nl\/parkeren-in\/amsterdam\/apcoa-parking-prins-keizer.html","urltitle":"Apcoa Parking Prins & Keizer","adres":"Prinsengracht 927","postcode":"1017HL","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","aantal":"140","opmerkingen":""}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"Qpark De Bijenkorf","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.895162,52.373881]}","type":"CommercieleParkeergarage","url":"https:\/\/www.q-park.nl\/nl-nl\/parkeren\/amsterdam\/de-bijenkorf\/","urltitle":"Qpark De Bijenkorf","adres":"Beursplein 15","postcode":"1012JW","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":""}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"Qpark Nieuwendijk","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.8944693,52.3764423]}","type":"CommercieleParkeergarage","url":"https:\/\/www.q-park.nl\/nl-nl\/parkeren\/amsterdam\/nieuwendijk\/","urltitle":"Qpark Nieuwendijk","adres":"Nieuwezijds Kolk 18","postcode":"1012PV","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":""}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"(P1) Parking Amsterdam Centre","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.8970068,52.3785141]}","type":"CommercieleParkeergarage","url":"http:\/\/www.p1.nl\/parkeren\/p1-parking-amsterdam-centre\/","urltitle":"P1 Parking Amsterdam Centre ","adres":"Prins Hendrikkade 20 a","postcode":"1012TL","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":""}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"Parkeergarage Apcoa Heinekenplein","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.8924871,52.3571537]}","type":"CommercieleParkeergarage","url":"http:\/\/www.apcoa.nl\/parkeren-in\/amsterdam\/apcoa-parking-heinekenplein.html","urltitle":"Apcoa garage Heinekenplein ","adres":"Eerste Van der Helststraat 6","postcode":"1072NV","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":""}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"Qpark Museumplein","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.8798246,52.3571347]}","type":"CommercieleParkeergarage","url":"https:\/\/www.q-park.nl\/nl-nl\/parkeren\/amsterdam\/museumplein\/","urltitle":"Qpark Museumplein ","adres":"Van Baerlestraat 33 B","postcode":"1071AP","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":""}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"P4 en P5 Villa ArenA","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.9389632,52.3118578]}","type":"Parkeergarage","url":"https:\/\/www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeren-verkeer\/parkeergarages\/parkeergarages\/","urltitle":"Bekijk P4 en P5 Villa ArenA op www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeergarages ","adres":"De entree 7","postcode":"1101BH","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":""}},{"parkeerlocatie":{"title":"P4 en P5 Villa ArenA","Locatie":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.9389632,52.3118578]}","type":"Parkeergarage","url":"https:\/\/www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeren-verkeer\/parkeergarages\/parkeergarages\/","urltitle":"Bekijk P4 en P5 Villa ArenA op www.amsterdam.nl\/parkeergarages","adres":"De entree 7","postcode":"1101BH","woonplaats":"Amsterdam","opmerkingen":""}}
```

The current error message is "TypeError: string indices must be integers" but i think it should give all the titles of the parkeerlocatie.

Comment: And how do i fix that? Can you improve my code? (This is my first python - json experience)

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis What do you mean? `json.load()` parses it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> type(data)
<type 'dict'>
>>> data['parkeerlocaties']
<type 'list'>
```

So the code could be

```
import urllib, json
import requests
import json

with open('locaties.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    parkeerlocaties = data['parkeerlocaties']
    for parkeerlocatie in parkeerlocaties:
        print(parkeerlocatie['parkeerlocatie']['title'])
```

Answer (score 1):

`parkeerlocaties['parkeerlocatie']` is not a list, it's a dictionary. You should use `parkeerlocaties['parkeerlocaties']['title']`. And the title is a string, there's no reason to iterate over it (unless you want to process it character by character for some reason).

```
with open('locaties.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
for parkeerlocaties in data['parkeerlocaties']:
    print('Title: ', parkeerlocaties['parkeerlocaties']['title'])
```